# Android NDK builds .so but Unresolved inclusion for all includes

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm playing around sample application provided in the Android NDK kit.

I imported the Native audio example code. When I tried to some changes in .cpp file, it'll start showing unresolved inclusion for all includes and compilation errors. Has anyone faced this issue?

When I build the project ndk-build successfully builds .so file.

Android.mk file is as follows

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE    := native-audio-jni
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-audio-jni.c
    # for native audio
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lOpenSLES
    # for logging
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
    # for native asset manager
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Logs on Console are as follows.

> 12:01:55 **** Build of configuration Default for project NativeAudio
>   **** "C:\android-ndk\ndk-build.cmd" all "Compile thumb : native-audio-jni <= native-audio-jni.c SharedLibrary :
>   libnative-audio-jni.so Install : libnative-audio-jni.so =>
>   libs/armeabi/libnative-audio-jni.so 12:01:56 Build Finished (took
>   1s.242ms)

Comment: paste the logs of console.

Comment: 12:01:55 **** Build of configuration Default for project NativeAudio ****
"C:\\android-ndk\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
"Compile thumb : native-audio-jni <= native-audio-jni.c
SharedLibrary  : libnative-audio-jni.so
Install        : libnative-audio-jni.so => libs/armeabi/libnative-audio-jni.so

12:01:56 Build Finished (took 1s.242ms)

Comment: Please add those as a part of question, it shows that library is compiled successfully, where you are facing compilation error then?

Comment: Paste your Android.mk ,paste it in Question itself.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? There's known issues with the Eclipse C++ indexer when using the Android plugin

Comment: Your problem statement has some issues - you can't really say that it successfully builds **and** that it has unresolved inclusion and compile errors.  If these mutually exclusive results come from different versions of the code, or *different build methods* then you need to say so.

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone faced this issue?

The answer is strong positive:

- [Eclipse compiles successfully but still gives semantic errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786555/eclipse-compiles-successfully-but-still-gives-semantic-errors)
- [Eclipse indexer errors when using STL with Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375708/eclipse-indexer-errors-when-using-stl-with-android-ndk)
- [Eclipse ADT "... could not be resolved" with Android NDK and C files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360668/eclipse-adt-could-not-be-resolved-with-android-ndk-and-c-files)

… and more. Unfortunately, none of the solutions, even those accepted, is trustworthy. If you want a simple, limited, but sure remedy, simply disable the indexer.

**Update**

There is a workaround which involves switching the *indexer* from *Android GCC* toolchain to *Linux GCC* toolchain, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22647256/1525238, or https://stackoverflow.com/a/22935387/1525238.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22935387/1525238 for complete indexing capability. I see you have a similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22647256/1525238 and I think that's trustworthy enough given that it works properly.