# JNI parsing error using Eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, java-native-interface, native

Maybe it's my configuration problem but... My Eclipse shows error when i'm trying to do sth like this:

// let say that i have a vector like this:

```
std::vector<Point2f> someVec(/*init vector or sth...*/);
```

and i want to read a field or whatever like this:

```
someVec[0].x = 10;
```

but then Eclipse cry that it's error - x is not a property. Moreover sth like this is "invalid" too:

```
// both are 'invalid'
someVec.operator[](0);
// or 
someVec.at(0);
```

On the other hand I can do sth like this and now Eclipse doesn't see any problem:

```
Point2f& p = someVec[0];
p.x = 10;
```

This 'hack' works well:

```
someVec.data()[0].x;
```

Have ever had similar problem maybe?

Comment: It's not a solution, but it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16891713/192373

Comment: Well... Now i have not compilation error - it's good :) but sadly it's not the best solution coz Eclipse still doesn't show me code hints when using dot or arrow when using [] operator.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22935387/1525238 for complete indexing capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. I included stddef.h which define size_t and some other stuff. Now problem is solved.