# Lots of unresolve error in native cpp

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have imported a project into my workspace, previously it was working fine, but now as soon as i open my cpp files it start giving me error `xyz could not be resolved`, where `xyz` may be any field or method, here is problem log.

```
Field 'vm' could not be resolved    android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 112    Semantic Error
Method 'DetachCurrentThread' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 112    Semantic Error
Method 'DetachCurrentThread' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 83 Semantic Error
Field 'activity' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 112    Semantic Error
Method 'DetachCurrentThread' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 71 Semantic Error
Field 'activity' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 77 Semantic Error
Field 'activity' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 71 Semantic Error
Field 'vm' could not be resolved    android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 71 Semantic Error
Field 'activity' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 83 Semantic Error
Field 'vm' could not be resolved    android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 83 Semantic Error
Field 'vm' could not be resolved    android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 77 Semantic Error
Method 'DetachCurrentThread' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 77 Semantic Error
Method 'DetachCurrentThread' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 34 Semantic Error
Field 'vm' could not be resolved    android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 34 Semantic Error
Field 'vm' could not be resolved    android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 59 Semantic Error
Field 'activity' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 59 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
_jobject * CallObjectMethod(_jobject *, _jmethodID *, ...)
'   android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 67 Semantic Error
Method 'DetachCurrentThread' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 59 Semantic Error
Field 'clazz' could not be resolved android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 67 Semantic Error
Field 'activity' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 67 Semantic Error
Field 'activity' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 17 Semantic Error
Field 'vm' could not be resolved    android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 17 Semantic Error
Field 'activity' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 17 Semantic Error
Field 'vm' could not be resolved    android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 21 Semantic Error
Field 'activity' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 21 Semantic Error
Field 'activity' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 34 Semantic Error
Method 'AttachCurrentThread' could not be resolved  android_tools.cpp   /ImageTargets/jni   line 21 Semantic Error
```

Because of this issue i am unable to open my cpp files in jni, i have tried to build index but it didnot work. If i restart my eclipse all my error has been gone and if i compile everthing work fine and project run on device but problem start when i tried to open my cpp files it start giving me this kind of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click project -> properties -> C/C++ General -> Code Analysis -> Launching

Uncheck both, apply, and you should be good to go.

The same answer can be found here: [Eclipse compiles successfully but still gives semantic errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786555/eclipse-compiles-successfully-but-still-gives-semantic-errors?rq=1)