# Build errors with Android NDK only after opening native file

Tags: c++, android-ndk, adt, eclipse-cdt

Project builds, and runs on device correctly immediately after importing. However any attempt to open/change any .cpp/.h file in the jni folder immediately causes errors in the compilation process.

Namely can no longer resolve the necessary includes JNI/Android NDK/stl.

Error only occurs on Windows, currently utilizing the most current ADT Bundle, and NDK.

Error Message:
Unresolved inclusion x 
where x is any header file from JNI/Android/stl, in short any header not existent in the jni folder.

This only occurs after opening the file the first time in the editor.

Comment: Your problem is, most likely, related to the Eclipse *Indexer*, not to the build. To prove it, try **ndk-build**  in CMD shell.

Comment: Considering that it builds fine in the original workspace it seems that you may be correct. It is only an issue in a new workspace after importing the project. I need it to build in Eclipse after an import. Running the ndk-build in a shell does not meet that requirement. I know that the code builds and is valid. This is more of an issue with how Eclipse is importing it.

Comment: I only asked you to ndk-build to test my asssumption, which was not evident beyond reasonable doubt from the original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of *[Android NDK build, Method could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155676/android-ndk-build-method-could-not-be-resolved)* and/or *[Eclipse compiles successfully but still gives semantic errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786555/eclipse-compiles-successfully-but-still-gives-semantic-errors)*