# Android NDK build, Method could not be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt, ndk-build

I have an Android project with native code. I'm able to build native code from command line by calling `ndk-build` command with no errors or warnings. But when I open it in ADT it shows the following error.

[image]

Error message: `Method CallStaticIntMethod could not be resolved.` There are many files with similar errors in the project.

I double checked configuration and here is what I have. Android build, tool chain and includes are properly configured (see pictures below)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Required includes are also visible in the Project Explorer and they are valid (not empty and point to correct header files).

[image]

But when I `Clean` the project and `Build` it, the errors are still there. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Configuration: ADT 22.6.2, NDK r9d (64-bit), OSX 10.9.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some struggling with preferences, I finally found a solution. This is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788) in NDK plugin which was reported to AOSP but not yet fixed. A past of the answer is described in comment #50. Here is the sequence which worked our for me.

1. Open *Project Properties* -> *C/C++ Build* -> *Tool Chan Editor*
2. In the section `Used Tools` replace `Android GCC Compiler` with `GCC C Compiler`. If section is empty, just add `GCC C Compiler` entry in there.
   [image]
3. Open *Project Properties* -> *C/C++ General* -> *Paths and Symbols* and add directories, where your h-files to be included are located. Use *Move up* button to add a folder with your local includes (`/AudioPlayer/jni` in my case) to the first place. Then add platform and toolchains includes. Built-in includes should stay at the very bottom.
   [image]
   In my case the full paths to the toolchain includes were like below. These are built-in paths of original `Android GCC Compiler` toolchain, which we have replaced at step 2.

   ```
   /Tools/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/include
   /Tools/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/include-fixed
   ```
4. Press *OK* button, *clean* and *re-build* the project. All errors must go away. If they stay, try to remove them from *Problems* view and re-build project once again.

**Update:** I have found another place, where you can add paths to include files. However it appears to be Eclipse version dependent. *Project Settings -> C/C++ General -> Processor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> CDT User Settings Entries -> Add*. After I added the paths listed above, there is no compilation issues anymore. Development is fun again.

Comment: I did not have to do steps 1 and 2, so maybe not needed. Else this answer worked well for me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, i have tried this solution. My all errors in C code gone but the project name still shows error symbol and due to this i am unable to run the project. I don't know exactly whats going wrong. Please suggest further

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its caused by the IDE not knowing where all of your headers and any libs you linking again are. The errors are generated by the IDE's autocomplete/bug system. You can either fix your includes within eclipse or remove them as errors in the preferences. ﻿

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error and solved it by going to project->properties->discovery options and changing the discovery profile from managed build system to GCC, after changing to GCC C Complier from Android GCC Compiler and updating the include directories.

Comment: How is this answer any different from beworker's answer 6 months earlier? Also see "me too" answers in [What is a “protected” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764)

Comment: this is a different solution. beworker's answer didn't work for me. after I tried his solution, I fixed the problem by changing the discovery profile under discovery options. I'm not sure whether beworker's answer had anything to do with fixing the problem for me, I just thought I would mention that I tried his solution first just in case both steps were necessary.