# To include c++ headers in Eclipse for Android NDK project(Mac)

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, eclipse-adt, ndk-build

I'm working on an Android NDK project in which I have to use functionalities which needs c++ header files such as `iostream` , `sstream` , etc,. I have already did this in linux by adding `/usr/include/c++/4.7..` in `C++ Paths & Symbols` tab. But still din't find a way to do this in Mac. I have tried the following:

- I have simply included iostream header `#include<iostream>` , it shows the following error while build using ndk-build, `fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory`
- Added `android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include` in `C++ Paths and Symbols->Includes tab->cpp` , It doesn't change anything.
- In my Android.mk file,

  ```
   LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include
  ```

  it gave the following error:

  fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory

  I have also tried adding prebuilt shared library in Android.mk file , which gave the same error.
- Then made a search for the file `bits/c++config.h` , copied it in to the actual place it is looking for, it shows the same error for `osdefines.h` , I have copied all the files it is looking for , atlast it asked for `bits/memoryfwd.h` , but I can't find the file anywhere in my Mac.

What is the actual problem here? What should I do to include those headers in cpp files in my Android NDK project?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23158929/192373) solution?

Comment: @AlexCohn  Thank you , I have tried this too, nothing changed. Do you know how can I find the path of actual include directory for gcc or c++(default in mac) in mac? , If I can get the path I can solve this, hope so.

Comment: You can run `ndk-build V=1`

Comment: Try to set `APP_STL := gnustl_static`in your Application.mk

Comment: I am having the same issue with the `<functional>` header.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a file called `Application.mk` in the directory `projet_dir/jni/` (so it is `projet_dir/jni/Application.mk`).
2. Add the following line to that file

   ```
   APP_STL:=stlport_static
   ```
3. If you run into a shared_ptr error, try using `APP_STL := gnustl_static` instead.

(I had this exact same issue on Linux and the above resolved it for me.)