# Getting android NDK r9d to have C++11 support

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk

I can't seem to get the android NDK to have C++11 support. Considering I'm only porting another person's project to android through the ndk, I really don't have any experience with c++ before now.

My application.mk:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := all
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may be of use to you. http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/accessing-c11-features-of-the-android-nd/240168385

Comment: To work with the native code in ADT (eclipse), you may find _[this SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155676/android-ndk-build-method-could-not-be-resolved)_ helpful

Comment: consider using [CrystaX NDK](https://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk?format=php)

Comment: If you need to use non-GPL library due to contractual obligations, then see [Issue 216331: STLport does not support C++11](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216331) on the AOSP bug tracker.