# Enabling C++11 symbols resolution in Eclipse Juno ADT

Tags: c++, c++11, eclipse-adt

I'm using Eclipse Juno with the ADT (Android Developer Tools) plugin downloaded from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.

I created an Android application project with Native Support enabled (*right click on the project → "Android Tools" → "Add Native Support"*).

Despite targeting C++11 in my `Application.mk` and `Android.mk` files, Eclipse fails to resolve symbols like **std::thread** or **std::unique_ptr**, but when I build the project it compiles well: The only problem is C++11 symbols resolution.

How can I make Eclipse resolves C++ 2011 symbols correctly?

Comment: @HRold - you just have to wait the 8 hours and then post your answer. I've removed the "[Solved]" from the title and the answer. The answer is still in the revision history so you can recover it from there to post when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Eclipse Juno with ADT plugin can compile C++11 code but fails to resolve C++11 symbols, here is the procedure:

1. Open your `.cproject` file in a text editor.
2. Search the following line *(where XXXXXXXXX is a random number)*:

   ```
   <tool id="com.android.gcc.compiler.XXXXXXXXX" name="Android GCC Compiler" superClass="com.android.gcc.compiler">
   ```
3. Add the following into it:

   ```
   <option id="com.android.gcc.compiler.option.preprocessor.def.768340103" superClass="com.android.gcc.compiler.option.preprocessor.def" valueType="definedSymbols">
       <listOptionValue builtIn="true" value="__cplusplus=201103L"/>
       <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="__cplusplus=201103L"/>
       <listOptionValue builtIn="true" value="__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__"/>
       <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__"/>
   </option>
   ```

   You should have something like this (*where YYYYYYYYYY is also a random number*):

   ```
   <tool id="com.android.gcc.compiler.XXXXXXXXX" name="Android GCC Compiler" superClass="com.android.gcc.compiler">
       <option id="com.android.gcc.compiler.option.preprocessor.def.768340103" superClass="com.android.gcc.compiler.option.preprocessor.def" valueType="definedSymbols">
           <listOptionValue builtIn="true" value="__cplusplus=201103L"/>
           <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="__cplusplus=201103L"/>
           <listOptionValue builtIn="true" value="__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__"/>
           <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__"/>
       </option>
       <inputType id="com.android.gcc.inputType.YYYYYYYYYY" superClass="com.android.gcc.inputType"/>
   </tool>
   ```
4. **Save** modifications, **restart** eclipse and if C++11 symbols are still not resolved **rebuild your index** (*right click on the project → "Index" → "Rebuild"*).

---

*Because the "Symbols" tab was not visible in the C/C++ options of the project, I was forced to add these lines manually in the `.cproject` file in order to set the value of `__cplusplus` to `201103L`.*

*I don't know exactly how .cproject files works so there's probably a better way to do it. I've seen some guys changing the toolset options of the project in order to make the "Symbols" tab visible (here [Android NDK build, Method could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155676/android-ndk-build-method-could-not-be-resolved) and here [Setting up C++11 (std::thread) for NDK with ADT/Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911019/setting-up-c11-stdthread-for-ndk-with-adt-eclipse)).*