# Red bugs appear but code compiles

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I have a project that includes both java, c++ and opencv. If I start eclipse and clean and compile my procect then everything compiles ok. I know that the C++ parts are compiling because if I first delete my ".so" file from libs/armeabi-v7a, then the ".so" file will appear again as soon as I click build. But then If I view the c++ source file in eclipse, I see loads of errors being marked by little red bugs down the left hand side of my code. For example next to "using namespace std:" It reports "symbol std could not be resolved". The project can now no longer be built or run (until I close eclipse and start it again - making sure not to view the C++ source).

What is causing this?

**EDIT:** there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786555/eclipse-compiles-successfully-but-still-gives-semantic-errors) asked nearly a year ago which had a work around (not a true solution). A comment read "the on-the-fly code analyzer for Android gcc in Eclipse seems to be not mature yet." - is that still the case one year on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse compiles successfully but still gives semantic errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786555/eclipse-compiles-successfully-but-still-gives-semantic-errors) . Note the workaround that involves defining the toolchain for code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pathing issue to me.  Eclipse doesn't know how to find headers for std namespace.

Check your paths.  If the code compiles, it'll be an Eclipse-only fix.

Comment: The path to my include files is correctly set in C/C++ general > Paths and symbols > includes .. is there somewhere else to look?